# How to handle paging in Gallery view?

Tags: android

I have a Gallery view, the view is loaded with 10 images.  The situation I'm struggling with is when the user scrolls to the end of the gallery how do I load the next 10 images?

I added a "Next" button to fetch the next 10 images the problem with this solution is when I switch the phones orientation to landscape gallery view wont scroll anymore. Plus I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285536/question-on-creating-a-gallery-view-containing-buttons) 
that you cannot put interactive controls in Gallery view.

If I implement the onScroll() or onFling() methods then I will be fetching the next 10 images without knowing if the user has reached the end of the first 10 in the view.

Your advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of solutions I can see.

First of all, create an image at the first/last spot to change gallery view. onClick() is supported I believe, and you can see the gallery that was selected.

The second is to have the controls outside of the gallery, ie, right below the gallery view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I used the second option.